# Populate an input with the contents of a custom option (data-) attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the example below, I'm trying to populate an input with the contents of the option.data-foo attribute. I *feel* like this close... but I've got something back-to-front somewhere... Any thoughts?

---

**My code :**

```js
function updateText(type) {
    var id = type+'Text';
    document.getElementById(id).data-foo = document.getElementById(type).value;
}
```

```html
<form id="example" name="example">
    <select id="sensor" onchange="updateText('sensor')">
        <option value="Jval" data-foo="Jfoo">Joption</option>
        <option value="Kval" data-foo="Kfoo">Koption</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <input type="text" value="" id="sensorText" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery then use this:

```
$('#sensor').change(function() {
  $('#sensorText').val( $(this).find('option:selected').data('foo') )
})
```

```js
$('#sensor').change(function() {
  $('#sensorText').val( $(this).find('option:selected').data('foo') )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="example" name="example">
  <select id="sensor">
    <option value="Jval" data-foo="Jfoo">Joption</option>
    <option value="Kval" data-foo="Kfoo">Koption</option>
  </select>

  <br />
  <input type="text" value="" id="sensorText" />
</form>
```

Comment: The snippet works here, but doesn't work if I cut and paste it locally, even if I update 1.11.1/jquery.min.js with a more recent version. And the Web Console does not report any error either ...
I was actually looking for a way to generalize the snippet when the option contains more than one data attribute, and they should be used to populate a different input each.

Answer (score 1):

What you're going for, is probably this :

```js
var selectField = document.getElementById('sensor');
var textField = document.getElementById('sensorText');
var updateTextField = function() {
    textField.setAttribute(
        'value',
        selectField.options[selectField.selectedIndex].dataset.foo
    );
}

// Populate your text field when loading your page
updateTextField();

// Update your text field when an option is selected
selectField.addEventListener('change', updateTextField);
```

```html
<form id="example" name="example">
    <select id="sensor">
        <option value="Jval" data-foo="Jfoo">Joption</option>
        <option value="Kval" data-foo="Kfoo">Koption</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="text" value="" id="sensorText" />
</form>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jk6qefhv/7/))

Answer (score 1):

You can also resolve it in this way

```js
$("#sensor").on("change", function(){
  var $selectedItem = $(this).find(":selected");
  var dataValue = $selectedItem.data("foo");
  $("#sensorText").val(dataValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="example" name="example">
    <select id="sensor">
        <option value="Jval" data-foo="Jfoo">Joption</option>
        <option value="Kval" data-foo="Kfoo">Koption</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <input type="text" value="" id="sensorText" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jquery:

```
var value = $('#elementId').attr('data-foo');
```

Comment: This approach will not work with select inputs as you need to find the selected attribute before you can grab the data attribute. Check the accepted answer for an example.