# Persuading scripts to play nicely together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been playing around with javascript/jquery, trying to get various bits of script to play nicely together (see for instance my recent question at [Populate an input with the contents of a custom option (data-) attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512023/populate-an-input-with-the-contents-of-a-custom-option-data-attribute)).

I've now got a clunky mass of code that kind of works. It's supposed to do 4 things:

1. Populate a cascading dropdown, whereby the options in the second dropdown vary according to whatever was selected in the first dropdown.
2. Clone the first row (or it could be the last row), so additional rows can be added to the form (in the real version there could be any number of rows when the page first loads)
3. Keep a running total of values selected in a 3rd drop down
4. Populate a text input based upon values selected in the second dropdown

For the first row everything works fine. However, for cloned rows steps 1 and 4 stop working. I suspect its because I haven't uniquely identified each cloned instance. Is that right? So how might I do that?

```js
    function cloneRow() {
      var row = document.getElementById("myrow"); // find row to copy
      var table = document.getElementById("mytable"); // find table to append to
      var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
      clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
      table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    }

    function createRow() {
      var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create row node
      var col = document.createElement('td'); // create column node
      var col2 = document.createElement('td'); // create second column node
      row.appendChild(col); // append first column to row
      row.appendChild(col2); // append second column to row
      col.innerHTML = "qwe"; // put data in first column
      col2.innerHTML = "rty"; // put data in second column
      var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
      table.appendChild(row); // append row to table
    }



window.sumInputs = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('hours'),
        result = document.getElementById('total'),
        sum = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        var ip = inputs[i];

        if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("total") < 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(ip.value) || 0;
        }

    }

    result.value = sum;
}


var myJson =
{
   "listItems":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "project_no":"1001",
         "task":[
            {
               "task_description":"Folding stuff",
               "id":"111",
               "task_summary":"Folding",
            },
            {
               "task_description":"Drawing stuff",
               "id":"222",
               "task_summary":"Drawing"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "project_no":"1002",
         "task":[
            {
               "task_description":"Meeting description",
               "id":"333",
               "task_summary":"Meeting"
            },
            {
               "task_description":"Administration",
               "id":"444",
               "task_summary":"Admin"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

$(function(){
  $.each(myJson.listItems, function (index, value) {
    $("#project").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.project_no+'</option>');
  });

    $('#project').on('change', function(){
      $('#task').html('<option value="000">-Select Task-</option>');
      for(var i = 0; i < myJson.listItems.length; i++)
      {
        if(myJson.listItems[i].id == $(this).val())
        {
           $.each(myJson.listItems[i].task, function (index, value) {
              $("#task").append('<option value="'+value.id+'" data-description="'+value.task_description+'">'+value.task_summary+'</option>');
          });
        }
      }
  });
});

$('#task').change(function() {
  $('#taskText').val( $(this).find('option:selected').data('description') )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<form>
 <table id='mytable'>
  <tr>
   <td>Project</td>
   <td>Workstage</td>
   <td>Hours</td>
   <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td><input size=3 id='total' disabled='disabled'/></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
   <tr id='myrow'>
   <td>
                  <select id="project" name="">
                      <option value="">Select One</option>
                    </select>
</td><td>
                   <select id="task" name="" onchange="updateText('task')">>
                       <option value="">Select One</option>
                  </select>
   </td>
   <td>
     <select name = 'hours' onmouseup="sumInputs()">
     <option>1.0</option>
     <option>1.5</option>
     <option>2.0</option>
     </select>
   <td><input type="text" value="" id="taskText" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
   <input type="button" onclick="cloneRow()" value="Add Row" />
</form>
```

Apologies if I've inserted the snippet incorrectly.

Comment: simply ensure each `id` in a page is **unique** - you'll have far fewer issues to deal with

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Yes. That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: It would help you to better conceptualize what you're accomplishing as manipulating your data (myJson) and representing said data -- and its methods -- as HTML elements. Your code for manipulating myJson can then focus on generating valid data and your presentation layer can be generalized to generate list items and tasks.

Comment: You have a very good answer from Ian, so if you believe that's the way to go, I don't see any point adding another answer, ... but if you'd hope for a solution with as less libraries to load as possible (none actually), this can be done in plain javascript. The benefit would be the best feature of them all, if you ask me, page load speed, so if your complexity is not going to increase dramatically and there will not be thousands of rows, let me know and I will post you an answer.

Comment: @LGSon I was looking at comparisons of load speeds this morning - some dramatic differences across frameworks & browsers, although a lot seemed to depend on precise implementation of frameworks, or structuring of JS in the 'raw' solutions. In truth, I doubt that this is going to get much more complex, and the data set for a given day is never going to be vast (let's say an average of 75 tasks across 50 projects in the current environment, so ca. 3750 items) , but I'm always keen to see how others would approach this. That said, Ian *is* looking like the front runner for the bounty!

Comment: Of course he is, it is a good solution (he got +1 from me), nevertheless, I will post an answer in the next 2-3 days, so hold on to the bounty until then :) ... Regarding load speed, you are absolutely right, implementation matters, though both server side and client side work load affects the total outcome, and when thousands users access as little as 50 kb, even milliseconds matter.

Comment: @Boris Serebrov have posted a really interesting solution using plain javascript (+1 from me and my choice of the way to go, so I will not post another one), which clearly shows that putting the same effort in learning what javascript can do, very often give the same very good solution, without the extra work load, dependency and learning time of a library.

Comment: @LGSon yes. However, the ease of adaptability which Ian was able to demonstrate - adding a further feature, later - makes me think that there really is something worthwhile in getting to grips with a framework. When I get my proper data set together, I'll run a test to see if there's significant difference in speed.

Comment: Of course, the whole point with them are to simplify, but make sure they justify as well. I just want to challenge them once in a while, and after all, they are all javascript, and if you aren't gonna use their full potential, they can quickly become a burden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest something completely different. I understand that your question was tagged with `jQuery` but I want to suggest a different and I believe better way of solving the problem.

I think here you're mixing your **DOM** and your **JavaScript** too much, and instead using a binding framework may be simpler. These binding frameworks split out your presentation from your underlying data. There are a number to chose from, here are but are just a few:

- Angular
- Knockout
- React

I personally know Knockout fairly well, so here is how I'd create something similar to that which you've produced using Knockout. Here I've reduced your code by about 50% and I believe significantly improved the readability with the bonus that I've removed all **DOM** from the JavaScript

Note that it's really easy to get your JSON view (my structure might not exactly match yours but should give you the idea) by using the **Knockout.mapping** plugin and calling `ko.toJS(vm.jobs)`

```js
var vm = {};

vm.projects = ko.observableArray([]);
vm.projects.push({
  id: 1001,
  name: "Project A",
  stages: [{ name: "folding", description: "folding stuff" }, 
           { name: "drawing", description: "drawing shapes" }]
});
vm.projects.push({
  id: 1002,
  name: "Project B",
  stages: [{ name: "meeting", description: "Talking" }, 
           { name: "admin", description: "everyday things" }]
});

vm.jobs = ko.observableArray([]);
vm.totalHours = ko.computed(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < vm.jobs().length; i++) {
    sum += vm.jobs()[i].time();
  }
  return sum;
})

createJob = function() {
  var job = {};

  // Set fields on the job
  job.project = ko.observable();
  job.stage = ko.observable();
  job.stages = ko.computed(function() {
    if (job.project()) return job.project().stages;
    return [];
  });
  job.stage.subscribe(function() {
    job.description(job.stage().description);
  });
  job.description = ko.observable();
  job.time = ko.observable(1);

  vm.jobs.push(job);
};

createJob();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table id='mytable'>
    <tr>
      <td>Project</td>
      <td>Workstage</td>
      <td>Hours</td>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input size=3 id='total' disabled='disabled' data-bind="value: totalHours" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: jobs -->
    <tr id='myrow'>
      <td>
        <select class="project" data-bind="options: $root.projects, optionsText: 'name', value: project, optionsCaption: 'Select a Project'"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="stage" data-bind="options: stages, value: stage, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select a Stage', enable: project()"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="hours" data-bind="options: [1.0, 1.5, 2.0], value: time, enable: stage()"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: description, enable: stage()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </table>
  <input type="button" onclick="createJob()" value="Add Row" />
</form>
```

The general idea here is that both the `observable` and the `observableArray` are bound to the **DOM** using `Knockout`. They'll automatically keep each other in sync.

The `computed` field is essentially a calculated field, so I've used that to generate your total, and also to feed one of the dropdowns - you could probably use a different approach but that seemed quite simple.

Finally there is a manual `subscribe` which is designed to update your default description for the `job` at hand. This allows you to update the field, without having to mess around with another observable or computed fields to override a description if the user set one.

As you've also had a problem with ID's for things, I'm also going to mention how you could address those. Using Knockout we could quite easily create client side unique ID's for our **DOM** using another computed field and returning it's order in the array:

```
job.id = ko.computed(function() {
   return vm.jobs.indexOf(job); 
});
```

You can then even reflect this in the **DOM** (note an ID can't start with a number) like so:

```
<td data-bind="attr: { id: 'job_' + id() }"></td>
```

This would produce DOM like:

```
<td id="job_0"></td>
```

Comment: Indeed, I would personally suggest this solution as well. jQuery is NOT a golden hammer, maybe it helps somewhere (lately I find it to be rarely useful) but if you want to solve given problem you shall use proper tools, and when it comes to databinding those mentioned above are the best, jquery dosn't help you at all as you found out by yourself.

Comment: That's beautiful - I can't give you a prize for making something more readable (the bar was set pretty low!), but I have to acknowledge that this is far more elegant than my own efforts. Clearly I have to do more research into these kinds of frameworks. Thanks again.

Comment: @Strawberry - you're welcome. Hopefully the development world will be a slightly better place. There's a whole host of binding frameworks to chose from, Knockout is a few years old so it's not the latest hammer anymore but I've found it to be brilliant for even some really sophisticated stuff with a really gentle learning curve. Feel free to read about a few and pick which suits your use case the best.

Comment: @Strawberry is there anything else you'd like me to elaborate on in my answer by the way? If there are things you'd like me to expand on or improve let me know and I'll try to update before your bounty expires :)

Comment: I don't really think so. Obviously, there are enhancements that could be considered, such as disabling the next dropdown until the previous dropdown has been selected - but these are things for me to explore from within the framework, assuming that that is the route I go down. (I'm building this thing in a very piecemeal approach, and not a method that I would advocate - but it's more a sort of 'proof of concept' at this stage)

Comment: @Strawberry - unfortunately prototype code has a nasty habit of making it to production. But in all reality at a PoC stage that's the best time to try something (even if it is new).

Comment: @Strawberry - decided to add the disabling of future dropdowns into the example for you - seeing as it was a 30 second change to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks again Ian. Can the applyBindings function be used to disable an option in one row that was previously selected in another? So, if project A: folding was selected in row one, that option would be disabled in all subsequent rows.

Comment: @Strawberry indeed - you could make selected options a computed and exclude any previously selected options.

Comment: When using this framework, is it necessary to fragment the json in the way in which you have? I would prefer to keep that intact.

Comment: @Strawberry no not at all. I did it for simplicity and understanding. By far the easiest way is to use [knockout.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). Calling `ko.mapping.fromJS(obj)` will convert a JavaScript object (may need to do `JSON.parse(json)` if you're dealing with actual JSON) and create all the observable and observableArray fields for you on a returned object.

Answer (score 3):

That's a really dirty peace of code. I solved your problem in the same dirty style but I recommend you to write everything completely new in a proper style.
I solved the problem by changing all id's to class attributes. And each row has it's own unique id.

```js
    var rowNum =1;
  
    function cloneRow() {
    var row = document.getElementById("row0"); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable"); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = "row"+rowNum; // change id or other attributes/contents
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    initProject(clone.id);
    rowNum++; 
  }

  function createRow() {
    var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create row node
    var col = document.createElement('td'); // create column node
    var col2 = document.createElement('td'); // create second column node
    row.appendChild(col); // append first column to row
    row.appendChild(col2); // append second column to row
    col.innerHTML = "qwe"; // put data in first column
    col2.innerHTML = "rty"; // put data in second column
    var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
    table.appendChild(row); // append row to table
  }



 window.sumInputs = function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByName('hours'),
   result = document.getElementById('total'),
   sum = 0;

  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
   var ip = inputs[i];

   if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("total") < 0) {
    sum += parseFloat(ip.value) || 0;
   }

  }

  result.value = sum;
 }


 var myJson =
 {
    "listItems":[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "project_no":"1001",
    "task":[
    {
       "task_description":"Folding stuff",
       "id":"111",
       "task_summary":"Folding",
    },
    {
       "task_description":"Drawing stuff",
       "id":"222",
       "task_summary":"Drawing"
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "project_no":"1002",
    "task":[
    {
       "task_description":"Meeting description",
       "id":"333",
       "task_summary":"Meeting"
    },
    {
       "task_description":"Administration",
       "id":"444",
       "task_summary":"Admin"
    }
    ]
    }
    ]
 }

 function initProject(rowId){
  
 console.log(rowId);
  if(rowId == 'row0'){
   $.each(myJson.listItems, function (index, value) {
    
   $("#"+rowId+" .project").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.project_no+'</option>');
    });
  }
  $('#'+rowId+' .project').on('change', function(e){
   rowElem = e.target.closest(".row");
   
   
   $('#'+rowId+' .task').html('<option value="000">-Select Task-</option>');
    for(var i = 0; i < myJson.listItems.length; i++)
    {
   
   if(myJson.listItems[i].id == $(this).val())
   {
      $.each(myJson.listItems[i].task, function (index, value) {
      $('#'+rowId+' .task').append('<option value="'+value.id+'" data-description="'+value.task_description+'">'+value.task_summary+'</option>');
     });
   }
    }
   });
   
   $('#'+rowId+' .task').change(function() {
   $('#'+rowId+' .taskText').val( $(this).find('option:selected').data('description') )
 })
 }
 initProject('row0');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form>
  <table id='mytable'>
   <tr>
    <td>Project</td>
    <td>Workstage</td>
    <td>Hours</td>
    <td>Description</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input size=3 id='total' disabled='disabled'/></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
    <tr id='row0' class="row">
    <td>
       <select class="project" name="">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
      </select>
 </td><td>
        <select class="task" name="" onchange="updateText('task')">
         <option value="">Select One</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td>
   <select name = 'hours' onmouseup="sumInputs()">
   <option>1.0</option>
   <option>1.5</option>
   <option>2.0</option>
   </select>
    <td><input type="text" value="" class="taskText" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
    <input type="button" onclick="cloneRow()" value="Add Row" />
 </form>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: That's superb. Thanks. I can barely see what you changed, so I'm going to have to study this carefully... I may be some time...

Comment: Yeah, it's even more horrific with those changes :( I stand by the fact the statement that  `code is foremost for other people to read and secondly for a computer to execute`

Answer (score 2):

Another version with simple templating system, this time without the jquery.

It was interesting to see if it will be difficult to convert, and it wasn't, most of things to map jQuery code to plain JS for modern browsers can be found here - [YOU MIGHT NOT NEED JQUERY](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Here is the code:

```js
var myJson =
{
   "listItems":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "project_no":"1001",
         "task":[
            {
               "task_description":"Folding stuff",
               "id":"111",
               "task_summary":"Folding",
            },
            {
               "task_description":"Drawing stuff",
               "id":"222",
               "task_summary":"Drawing"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "project_no":"1002",
         "task":[
            {
               "task_description":"Meeting description",
               "id":"333",
               "task_summary":"Meeting"
            },
            {
               "task_description":"Administration",
               "id":"444",
               "task_summary":"Admin"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

var template = function(target) {
  var _parent = target.parentNode;
  var _template = _parent.getAttribute('dataTemplate');
  if (!_template) {
    // no template yet - save it and remove the node from HTML
    target.style.display = '';
    target.classList.add('clone');
    _template = target.outerHTML;
    _parent.setAttribute('dataTemplate', JSON.stringify(_template));
    _parent.removeChild(target);
  } else {
    // use saved template
    _template = JSON.parse(_template);
  }
  return {
    populate: function(data) {
      var self = this;
      this.clear();
      data.forEach(function(value) {
        self.clone(value);
      });
    },
    clone: function(value) {
      var clone = target.cloneNode(true);
      _parent.appendChild(clone);
      var html = _template;
      if (value) {
        for (var key in value) {
          html = html.replace('{'+key+'}', value[key]);
        }
      }
      clone.outerHTML = html;
      clone = _parent.lastChild;
      if (value) {
        clone.setAttribute('dataTemplateData', JSON.stringify(value));
      }
      return clone;
    },
    clear: function() {
      var clones = _parent.querySelectorAll('.clone')
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(clones, function(el) {
        _parent.removeChild(el);
      });
    }
  };
};

function createRow() {
  var clone = template(document.querySelector('.myrow-template')).clone();
  template(clone.querySelector('.project-option-tpl')).populate(myJson.listItems);
  updateHours();
  bindEvents();
}

function bindEvents() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable .project');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('dataTemplateData'));
      template(this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.task-option-tpl')).populate(data.task);
    });
  });
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable .task');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('dataTemplateData'));
      this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.task-text').value = data.task_description;
    });
  });
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable .hours');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      updateHours();
    });
  });
}

function updateHours() {
  var total = 0;
  var hours = document.querySelectorAll('.hours');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(hours, function(item) {
    if (item.parentNode.parentNode.style.display.length == 0) {
      total += parseFloat(item.value) || 0;
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

ready(function(){
  createRow();
  document.querySelector('.add-row').addEventListener('click', function() {
    createRow();
  });
});
```

```html
    <form>
        <table id='mytable'>
            <tr>
                <td>Project</td>
                <td>Workstage</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
                <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input size=3 id='total' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='myrow-template' style='display:none'>
                <td>
                    <select class="project" name="">
                        <option value="">Select One</option>
                        <option class='project-option-tpl' value="{id}" style='display:none'>{project_no}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="task" name="">
                        <option value="000">-Select Task-</option>
                        <option class='task-option-tpl' value="{id}" data-description="{task_description}" style='display:none'>{task_summary}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='hours'>
                        <option>1.0</option>
                        <option>1.5</option>
                        <option>2.0</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" class="task-text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row" />
    </form>
```

Comment: I voted this one up being a very good plain javascript solution. The only major thing I would have done different, would be to store the clone in a variable for reuse, instead of having it polluting the markup. Now, when the form will be submitted, one need to add unnecessary coding, either client side or server side, to avoid getting that data mess up saving the result.

Comment: @Strawberry I will take a look on how to do that best way, post either a fiddle or an answer when done (within 24 hours).

Comment: @Strawberry @LGSon Actually the change like this is not complex, I updated the example above to cache the template code into variable and remove the invisible node from the markup (it saves the template into the `dataTemplate` attribute, to avoid putting it into HTML at all we could save it into the global `window` object). But actually with UI like this, the from will probably be submitted with ajax, so extra markup would not be a problem, just a js code which sends the data to the server could skip the invisible nodes.

Comment: @Strawberry Posted an answer for you, showing how it could look like.

Answer (score 1):

See the other answers why the current code is not working as expected. (in short: `id` may only appear once).

I took some time and reorganized your code. As for me personally it doesn't look that maintainable. I did use objects to neaten things up a bit. You could also use a framework like angular etc. But JavaScript in it self can also be really nice. And probably is good enough for something that small.

Some notes:

- The first row in my example is `display:none` and called template (this way we always have a "clean" template ready to use). You could have this template only in Javascript and insert it on demand, but this way will help you to quickly edit the design.
- There are 4 groups in my code

  - The data (myjson)
  - The table object declaration (this way you could also create multiple tables)
  - The row object declaration
  - The init preparation
- The prototype is useful because it doesn't duplicate the code for each row 
  (object). So every `select` will execute the same function. But since we use objects each time we have different data.
- Some functions have something like `hours.click(function(){tableElement.updateTime()});` this inner function is necessary as it keeps the scope of the function to the object and not the click event. Normally when you catch a click event and set a function, then in this function `this` is the click event. I used objects, so `this` should be the object and not the event.

```js
var myJson = {
  "listItems": [{
    "id": "1",
    "project_no": "1001",
    "task": [{
      "task_description": "Folding stuff",
      "id": "111",
      "task_summary": "Folding",
    }, {
      "task_description": "Drawing stuff",
      "id": "222",
      "task_summary": "Drawing"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "project_no": "1002",
    "task": [{
      "task_description": "Meeting description",
      "id": "333",
      "task_summary": "Meeting"
    }, {
      "task_description": "Administration",
      "id": "444",
      "task_summary": "Admin"
    }]
  }]
};

/*
  Table
*/
function projectPlan(tableElement) { // Constructor
  this.tableElement = tableElement;
  this.totalTimeElement = tableElement.find('tr td input.total');
  this.rows = [];
};

projectPlan.prototype.appendRow = function(template) { // you could provide different templates
  var newRow = template.clone().toggle(); // make a copy and make it visible
  this.tableElement.append(newRow);
  this.rows.push( new workRow(newRow, this) );
  
  // update the time right away
  this.updateTime();
};

projectPlan.prototype.updateTime =  function() {
  var totalWork = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) totalWork += this.rows[i].hours.val()*1; // *1 makes it a number, default is string
  this.totalTimeElement.val(totalWork);
};

/*
  Row
*/
function workRow(rowElement, tableElement) { // Constructor
    // set the object attributes with "this"
    this.rowElement = rowElement;
    this.tableElement = tableElement;
    this.projects = rowElement.find( "td select.projects" );
    this.tasks = rowElement.find( "td select.tasks" );
    this.hours = rowElement.find( "td select.hours" );
    this.taskText = rowElement.find( "td input.taskText" );
  
    // set all the event listeners, don't use this since the "function(){" will have a new scope
    var self = this;
    this.projects.change(function(){self.updateTasks()});
    this.tasks.change(function(){self.updateTaskText()});
    this.hours.change(function(){tableElement.updateTime()});
  
}

workRow.prototype.updateTasks =  function() {
  // delete the old ones // not the first because it's the title
  this.tasks.find('option:not(:first-child)').remove();
  
  if(this.projects.val() != "-1") {
    var tmpData;
    for (var i = 0; i < myJson.listItems[this.projects.val()].task.length; i++) {
      tmpData = myJson.listItems[this.projects.val()].task[i];
      this.tasks.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + tmpData.task_summary + '</option>');
    }
  }
  
  this.taskText.val('');
  
}

workRow.prototype.updateTaskText =  function() {
  if(this.tasks.val() == "-1") this.taskText.val('');
  else this.taskText.val( myJson.listItems[ this.projects.val() ].task[ this.tasks.val() ].task_description );
  
}

/* 
  Setup 
*/

// Prepare the template (insert as much as possible now)
rowTemplate = $('#rowTemplate');
var projectList = rowTemplate.find( "td select.projects" );
var tmpData;
for (var i = 0; i < myJson.listItems.length; i++) {
  tmpData = myJson.listItems[i];
  projectList.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + tmpData.project_no + '</option>');
}

// setup table
var projectPlan = new projectPlan( $('#projectPlan') );

// Print the first row
projectPlan.appendRow(rowTemplate);
$('#buttonAddRow').click(function(){ projectPlan.appendRow(rowTemplate) });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table id="projectPlan">
    <tr>
      <td>Project</td>
      <td>Workstage</td>
      <td>Hours</td>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input size=3 class='total' disabled='disabled' /></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id='rowTemplate' style="display:none">
      
      <td>
        <select class="projects">
           <option value="-1">Select One</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="tasks">>
           <option value="-1">Select One</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class='hours'>
         <option>1.0</option>
         <option>1.5</option>
         <option>2.0</option>
        </select>
      </td> 
      <td>
        <input class="taskText" type="text"/>
      </td>
      
    </tr>
    
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="buttonAddRow" value="Add Row" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the answer about Angular / Knokout / React - this is actually what I highly recommend to use in the real application.

Just as an exercise, here is how the code can look like if you use a simple templating system.

The idea is that you should not build the javascript "manually" and instead declare the templates in the HTML. For example the projects select can look like this:

```
<select class="project" name="">                                                                 
    <option value="">Select One</option>                                                         
    <option class='project-option-tpl' value="{id}" style='display:none'>{project_no}</o
</select>
```

Here the `option` is an invisible template for project options. It works similar for the whole "row" and "tasks" select, here is the full code to implement the logic:

```
function createRow() {
  var $clone = template($('.myrow-template')).clone();
  template($clone.find('.project-option-tpl')).populate(myJson.listItems);
  updateHours();
}

function updateHours() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.hours:visible').each(function (index, item) {
    total += parseFloat($(item).val()) || 0;
  });
  $('#total').val(total);
}

$(function() {
  createRow();  // create the first row
  $('#mytable').on('change', '.project', function() {
    // handle project change - get tasks for the selected project
    // and populate the tasks template
    var data = $(this).find(':selected').data('template-data');
    template($(this).parent().parent().find('.task-option-tpl')).populate(data.task);
  });
  $('#mytable').on('change', '.task', function() {
    // task change - update the task description
    var data = $(this).find(':selected').data('template-data');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.task-text').val(data.task_description);
  });
  $('#mytable').on('mouseup', '.hours',function() {
    updateHours(); // re-calculate total hours
  });
  $('.add-row').on('click', function() {
    createRow(); // add one more row
  });
});
```

The "magic" is implemented in the `template` function:

```
var template = function($target) {
  $target = $($target.get(0));
  return {
    populate: function(data) {
      // for each item in the data array - clone and populate the
      // item template
      var self = this;
      this.clear();
      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        self.clone(value);
      });
    },
    clone: function(value) {
      // clone a template for a single item and populate it with data
      var $clone = $target.clone();
      $clone.addClass('clone').appendTo($target.parent()).fadeIn('slow');
      if (value) {
        var html = $clone.get(0).outerHTML;
        for (var key in value) {
          html = html.replace('{'+key+'}', value[key]);
        }
        $clone.get(0).outerHTML = html;
        $clone = $target.parent().find(':last')
        $clone.data('template-data', value);
      }
      return $clone;
    },
    clear: function() {
      // remove cloned templates
      $target.parent().find('.clone').remove();
    }
  };
};
```

Here is the full runnable example:

```js
var myJson =
{
   "listItems":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "project_no":"1001",
         "task":[
            {
               "task_description":"Folding stuff",
               "id":"111",
               "task_summary":"Folding",
            },
            {
               "task_description":"Drawing stuff",
               "id":"222",
               "task_summary":"Drawing"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "project_no":"1002",
         "task":[
            {
               "task_description":"Meeting description",
               "id":"333",
               "task_summary":"Meeting"
            },
            {
               "task_description":"Administration",
               "id":"444",
               "task_summary":"Admin"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

var template = function($target) {
  $target = $($target.get(0));
  return {
    populate: function(data) {
      var self = this;
      this.clear();
      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        self.clone(value);
      });
    },
    clone: function(value) {
      var $clone = $target.clone();
      $clone.addClass('clone').appendTo($target.parent()).fadeIn('slow');
      if (value) {
        var html = $clone.get(0).outerHTML;
        for (var key in value) {
          html = html.replace('{'+key+'}', value[key]);
        }
        $clone.get(0).outerHTML = html;
        $clone = $target.parent().find(':last')
        $clone.data('template-data', value);
      }
      return $clone;
    },
    clear: function() {
      $target.parent().find('.clone').remove();
    }
  };
};

function createRow() {
  var $clone = template($('.myrow-template')).clone();
  template($clone.find('.project-option-tpl')).populate(myJson.listItems);
  updateHours();
}

function updateHours() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.hours:visible').each(function (index, item) {
    total += parseFloat($(item).val()) || 0;
  });
  $('#total').val(total);
}

$(function(){
  createRow();
  $('#mytable').on('change', '.project', function() {
    var data = $(this).find(':selected').data('template-data');
    template($(this).parent().parent().find('.task-option-tpl')).populate(data.task);
  });
  $('#mytable').on('change', '.task', function() {
    var data = $(this).find(':selected').data('template-data');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.task-text').val(data.task_description);
  });
  $('#mytable').on('mouseup', '.hours',function() {
    updateHours();
  });
  $('.add-row').on('click', function() {
    createRow();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
        <table id='mytable'>
            <tr>
                <td>Project</td>
                <td>Workstage</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
                <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input size=3 id='total' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='myrow-template' style='display:none'>
                <td>
                    <select class="project" name="">
                        <option value="">Select One</option>
                        <option class='project-option-tpl' value="{id}" style='display:none'>{project_no}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="task" name="">
                        <option value="000">-Select Task-</option>
                        <option class='task-option-tpl' value="{id}" data-description="{task_description}" style='display:none'>{task_summary}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='hours'>
                        <option>1.0</option>
                        <option>1.5</option>
                        <option>2.0</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" class="task-text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

And angular.js version, here is the complete application code, the rest is declared in the HTML:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
   .controller('TasksController', function() {
     var self = this;
     this.newRow = function() {
       return { project: null, task: null, hours: 1.0 };
     };
     this.total = 0;
     this.hours = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0];
     this.projects = projects;
     this.rows = [ this.newRow() ];
     this.total = function() {
       return this.rows.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
         return prev + parseFloat(curr.hours);
       }, 0);
     };
     this.addRow = function() {
       this.rows.push(this.newRow());
     };
   });
```

The full code:

```js
var projects = [{
   "id":"1",
   "project_no":"1001",
   "task":[ {
         "task_description":"Folding stuff",
         "id":"111",
         "task_summary":"Folding",
      }, {
         "task_description":"Drawing stuff",
         "id":"222",
         "task_summary":"Drawing"
      } ]
}, {
   "id":"2",
   "project_no":"1002",
   "task":[ {
         "task_description":"Meeting description",
         "id":"333",
         "task_summary":"Meeting"
      }, {
         "task_description":"Administration",
         "id":"444",
         "task_summary":"Admin"
      } ]
}];

 angular.module('MyApp', [])
   .controller('TasksController', function() {
     var self = this;
     this.newRow = function() {
       return { project: null, task: null, hours: 1.0 };
     };
     this.total = 0;
     this.hours = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0];
     this.projects = projects;
     this.rows = [ this.newRow() ];
     this.total = function() {
       return this.rows.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
         return prev + parseFloat(curr.hours);
       }, 0);
     };
     this.addRow = function() {
       this.rows.push(this.newRow());
     };
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <form ng-controller="TasksController as ctrl">
        <table id='mytable'>
            <tr>
                <td>Project</td>
                <td>Workstage</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
                <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input size=3 id='total' value="{{ctrl.total()}}" disabled='disabled'/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.rows">
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="row.project" ng-options="project as project.project_no for project in ctrl.projects">
                        <option value="">Select One</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="row.task" ng-options="task as task.task_summary for task in row.project.task">
                        <option value="">Select Task</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <select ng-model='row.hours' ng-options="hour as (hour | number : 1) for hour in ctrl.hours">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{row.task.task_description}}" class="task-text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" ng-click="ctrl.addRow()" value="Add Row" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using plain javascript, which doesn't need/use element id's, store the clone as a variable, disabled task select unless a project is chosen.

This code sample can of course be optimized, wrapped in to classes etc. though I chose not to, to make it as easy as possible to follow the code flow and see what's going on.

```js
var myJson =
    {
      "listItems":[
        {
          "id":"1",
          "project_no":"1001",
          "task":[
            {
              "task_description":"Folding stuff",
              "id":"111",
              "task_summary":"Folding",
            },
            {
              "task_description":"Drawing stuff",
              "id":"222",
              "task_summary":"Drawing"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id":"2",
          "project_no":"1002",
          "task":[
            {
              "task_description":"Meeting description",
              "id":"333",
              "task_summary":"Meeting"
            },
            {
              "task_description":"Administration",
              "id":"444",
              "task_summary":"Admin"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

var template = function(target) {
  return {
  
    clone: function(value) {
      if (!template.clone_item) {
        
        // create clone variable
        template.clone_item = target.cloneNode(true);
        
        return target;
      } else {
        
        // return/append clone variable
        return target.parentNode.appendChild(template.clone_item.cloneNode(true));
      }
    },
    
    init: function(value) {

      // first select (projects)        
      var sel = target.querySelector('select');
      sel.addEventListener('change', function() {

        // second select (tasks)
        var sel = target.querySelectorAll('select')[1];
        sel.addEventListener('change', function() {

          var selvalues = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value.split('|');
          var data = value[selvalues[0]].task[selvalues[1]].task_description;

          // last inout (tasks descript.)        
          var inp = target.querySelector('input');
          inp.value = data;

        });

        // clear last used task select options
        for (i=sel.length-1;sel.length >1;i--) {
          sel.remove(i);
        }

        // clear last used task descript.
        var inp = target.querySelector('input');
        inp.value = '';

        // disable task select
        sel.disabled = true;

        // add task select options
        var selvalue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selvalue != '') {
          sel.disabled = false;
          var data = value[selvalue].task;
          var index = 0;
          for (var key in data) {
            createOption(sel,selvalue + '|' + index++,data[key].task_summary);
          }
        }

      });
      var index = 0;

      // add project select options
      for (var key in value) {
        createOption(sel,index++,value[key].project_no);
      }

      // hours
      var inp = target.querySelector('.hours');
      inp.addEventListener('change', function() {
        updateHours();
      });
      updateHours();
        
    }
  };
};

function createRow() {
  var clone = template(document.querySelector('.myrow')).clone();
  template(clone).init(myJson.listItems);
}

function createOption(sel,val,txt) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = val;
  opt.text = txt;
  sel.add(opt);
}

function updateHours() {
  var total = 0;
  var hours = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable .hours');
  for (i = 0; i < hours.length;i++) {
    total += parseFloat(hours[i].value) || 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;  
}

function ready(fn) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

ready(function(){
  createRow();
  document.querySelector('.add-row').addEventListener('click', function() {
    createRow();
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <table id='mytable'>
    <tr>
      <td>Project</td>
      <td>Workstage</td>
      <td>Hours</td>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input size=3 id='total' disabled='disabled'/></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='myrow'>
      <td>
        <select class="project" name="">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="task" name="" disabled=disabled>
          <option value="000">-Select Task-</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class='hours'>
          <option>1.0</option>
          <option>1.5</option>
          <option>2.0</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" class="task-text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row" />
</form>
```